# jQuery Tokeninput - Add new tag - Issue if new token is substring of any existing token

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, tokenize, jquery-tokeninput

Look at following scenario:

[image]

I have added a token called "facebook". I want to add a new token called "book". If I write book and press enter, it automatically selects facebook instead of adding new tag called "book".

Is there any solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```js
  $(function(){
  var availableTags = [
                       "actionscript",
                       "applescript",
                       "asp",
                       "basic",
                       "c",
                       "c++",
                       "clojure",
                       "coldfusion",
                       "erlang",
                       "fortran",
                       "groovy",
                       "haskell",
                       "java",
                       "javascript",
                       "lisp",
                       "perl",
                       "php",
                       "Python",
                       "ruby",
                       "scala",
                       "scheme"
                     ];
                     $( "#etags" ).autocomplete({
                       source: availableTags
                     });
 
                     
    $('#tags input').on('focusout',function(){    
      var txt= this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\+\-\.\#]/g,''); // allowed characters
      if(txt) {
       var flag = false;
       $(".tag").each(function()
       {
      var id = $(this).attr("id"); 
      if(id == txt)
      {
       flag = true;
      }  
       });
       if(flag)
       {
        alert("Tag already exist!!")
       } 
       else
       {
        $(this).before('<span class="tag" id ='+txt+' >'+ txt.toLowerCase() +'</span>');
       }    
       
              
      }
      this.value="";
    }).on('keyup',function( e ){
      // if: comma,enter (delimit more keyCodes with | pipe)
      if(/(188|13)/.test(e.which)) $(this).focusout(); 
 
    });
    
    
    $('#tags').on('click','.tag',function(){
       if(confirm("Really delete this tag?")) $(this).remove(); 
    });
 
  });
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<title>Multiple tags Seperated by comma or Enter by Balram Singh</title>
  
  
  <div id="tags">
<span class="tag" id="Wordpress">wordpress</span>
<span class="tag" id="c++">c++</span>
<span class="tag" id="jquery">jquery</span>
<input type="text" id="etags"  value="" placeholder="Enter multiple Tags Seperate by comma or Enter " />
  </div>
```

Comment: I also want a list of added tags while adding a new tag so that if a tag already exists then I can select it from the list itself. Also, the same tag can not be added multiple times. I have used jQuery tokeninput plugin : http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/